# How to click css selector by text using selenium python

Tags: python, ajax, selenium, selenium-webdriver, onclick

I would like to test some actions. In this case, I need to click on the text to get an upload form, but none of the forms below do not lead to the desired result.

This part of HTML-code, where I need to do some actions:

```html
<a href="javascript:;" class="dg-hider st-mb__20 st_add-material__link" onclick="iu.ajax(event,'https://alexanderro.com/ajax/documentAddGsiUpload');">
            Choose your category
        </a>
<div id="GSIData"></div>
```

none of these works:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "dg-hider st-mb__20 st_add-material__link"))).click()

driver.find_element_by_class_name("dg-hider st-mb__20 st_add-material__link").click()

driver.find_element_by_id("GSIData").click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "GSIData"))).click()

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[onclick*=https://alexanderro.com/ajax/documentAddGsiUpload]").click()
```

Could you help me?

Comment: do you get any error? are you sure that your locators are not in an iframe?

Comment: @Razvan the page doesn't contain any frames

Comment: Can you provide the website link.

Comment: @АлександрОрешкевич posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the element for its presence or visibility:

You can use the below code snippet, it should work

```
def wait_for_element_to_be_clickable(element):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, element)))


element = "a.dg-hider.st-mb__20.st_add-material__link"
wait_for_element_to_be_clickable(element)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(element).click()
print("Clicked")
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't make a comment in Stack Overflow, so I'll try help you throug here:

Did you try:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[class="dg-hider st-mb__20 st_add-material__link"]').click()

or 

driver.find_element_by_xpath('"//a[contains(text(), 'Choose your category')]"').click()
```